SQL Server Filestream empty files
We're using Filestream to store files in the database.
The setup to write is exactly as specified here.
This works fine: the file is written to the server and we can read the file and display it.
Recently we started doing some load testing to see how the Filestream would perform with a lot of files being written to it.
That's when we discovered that sometimes the files that are written to the server are empty.
Do you have any ideas why?

Are you writing using sql server or C# stuff? And are you logging exceptions? Gonna probably need some code to recreate the issue

Hard to say without seeing some code, but I'd guess someone is forgetting to close the file or the command, or there is an error which you are ignoring.
